# Time Reversal Operator for two-level system

Tags: quantum-spin, time-reversal-symmetry, two-level-system

Does the time-reversal operator have the same effect on on the Pauli matrices if we consider a two-level system which does not represent a physical spin-1/2 particle?

Answer (score 0):

No, for arbitrary two level system time-reversal is equivalent to only complex conjugation. The nature of spin, namely direction flipping under time reversal, is crucial in order to have Pauli matrices in the transformation.

Comment: So if I'm applying the time reversal operator to a Hamiltonian describing a two-level system (but specifically not one describing a spin) i just take the complex conjugate of coefficients but leave the Pauli matrices alone? Do you know of any references that show this starting from the full description of the spinless particle, applying time-reversal and then truncating the  Hilbert space?

Comment: Sakurai "Modern Quantum Mechanics", starting from p. 289. If your states are constructed from the regular position basis, then under time reversal all positions basis vectors remain the same, but the coefficients become complex conjugate due to antiunitary nature of the time-reversal operator